# Content Organiser upload dialog

Tags: document-library, file-upload, content-organizer

I am using the Content Organiser to send uploaded files from a subsite DropOff folder to the root website.

The documents to be uploaded have a custom content type and who's parent is the Document Content Type.

My first issue is that when I browse and submit the file to be uploaded, the following dialog (where you fill in the other fields) has a height which is too small and a scrollbar appears with only two fields displayed in the visible area.

Is there a fix for this (I checked that no custom css was overriding sharepoint css)?

Secondly, there is a dropdown box (Content Type), whose default value is "Document" and I have to always select "MyCustomContentType" from the list and then fill in the fields.

Is there anyway to remove the "Document" option or default to "MyCustomContentType"?

Third - is there any way to remove/hide the toolbar? The option to "Check-In" the document is going to confuse users.

Screenshot below:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. To remove the Document content type from display simply via Library Settings - Content Types and either use the Change Order and un-check the visible check-box or remove it for good from Library (in this case BEFORE attempting to remove it, you need to make sure all documents using this content type have been already updated to the other content type of your interest)
2. The toolbar is the actual ribbon. Unless you really change the master page and use the #s4-ribbonrow with display:none (but only by appending .msdialog CSS class), something like .ms-dialog #s4-ribbonrow {display:none;} (not actually tested as it is not something really recomanded because you'll loose a lot of functionality on every dialog, not just this List)
3. Are you sure the wrong size isn't due to some faulty CSS classes, particularly in the area of #s4-workspace (e.g. manipulating "overflow" properties or width/height could cause that!)

Comment: I have done as per your 1st point however it's still not working as it should be. I think it's because my document library is a webpart on a subsite, which uses data from the root website :O (Yeah shoulda told you that).

Comment: I'll have to bypass the ribbon hiding then, as that could cause more problems than I already have!

Comment: Will check css again, but theres not much to see there :O Thanks!

Comment: If the Web part is aggregating content (DWVP or CQWP) it would also mean the "Document" CT could be coming from one of the Libraries. It is up to you do apply or not these changes depending on your requirements.

Comment: The method I used to share my root library with subsites is here: http://blog.concurrency.com/sharepoint/creating-global-list-or-library-web-parts-with-sharepoint-designer-2010/
I believe it's an XlstListView

Comment: This is a regular ListViewWebPart, so it should comply to the rules of the Library to which is connected!